# Why are these conditions necessary to form a vector bundle from a complex?

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

I am busy with my thesis and I've encountered a claim about short sequences I don't fully understand. Here x is some value in a complex manifold $M$.

We have two maps $\alpha_x$ and $\beta_x$ such that $\beta_x \circ \alpha_x=0$ and they form a family of complexes as follows: $K_0 \stackrel{\alpha_x}{\rightarrow}K_1\stackrel{\beta_x}{\rightarrow} K_2$. From this family of complexes I want to make a vector bundle by associating $\text{ker }\beta_x /\text{im } \alpha_z$ with each point in $M$.

It is stated that it is necessary for $\alpha_x$ to be injective and $\beta_x$ to be surjective, but why?

I know that they should be injective and surjective if we want an exact short sequence, but if this was exact then our bundle would not really add something.

Comment: "It is stated": by who? Where? I think your question is a little unclear and would benefit from a bit more context and explanation.

Comment: I'm trying to follow a master thesis written by AJ Lindenhovius and this is stated on page 83. The context is that we have two holomorphic bundle maps between trivial vector bundles K_i over M and we want to make a new (non-trivial) bundle by $E_x=\text{ker }\beta_x /\text{Im} \alpha_x$.

Answer (score 1):

Injectivity of $\alpha$ and surjectivity of $\beta$ are sufficient conditions for the cohomology sheaf
$$
\operatorname{Ker}(\beta)/\operatorname{Im}(\alpha)
$$
to be a vector bundle, but they are not necessary. A more relaxed sufficient condition is that the ranks of $\alpha_x$ and $\beta_x$ are **constant**, i.e., do not depend on the point $x$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was so put off by thinking it had to do something with exact sequences.